# Angular 6 material animations do not work

Tags: angular, angular-material

Animations in material components do not work. I tried to put the component sidenav and the menu, and the smooth animation does not work. I think the problem with BrowserAnimationsModule, because when I remove it from package.json nothing happens, although when you install the material it is required.
................................................................................................................................................................................

#### File *package.json*

```
   {
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.5",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

#### File *app.component.html*

```
 <div class="example-container"
     [class.example-is-mobile]="mobileQuery.matches"
     *ngIf="shouldRun">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary"
                 class="example-toolbar">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="snav.toggle()">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <h1 class="example-app-name">CHEMEXSOL</h1>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-container"
                           [style.marginTop.px]="mobileQuery.matches ? 56 : 0">
        <mat-sidenav #snav
                     [mode]="mobileQuery.matches ? 'over' : 'side'"
                     [fixedInViewport]="mobileQuery.matches">
            <mat-nav-list>
                <a mat-list-item routerLink="."
                   *ngFor="let nav of fillerNav">{{nav}}</a>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-sidenav>

        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
            </mat-menu>

            <p *ngFor="let content of fillerContent">{{content}}</p>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!shouldRun">Please open on Stackblitz to see result</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
  import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {MediaMatcher} from '@angular/cdk/layout';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
    mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;

    shouldRun = true;

    fillerNav = Array(50).fill(0).map((_, i) => `Nav Item 14313413 ${i + 1}`);

    fillerContent = Array(50).fill(0).map(() =>
        `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
       labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
       laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
       cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`);

    private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

    constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher) {
        this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
        this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
    }
}
```

#### File *app.module.ts*

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule
} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatMenuModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatMenuModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Yes in the demo works, it's a demo from the site of the material

Comment: In a real project does not work

Comment: well, sorry if not so composed the question, the point is that I installed the material and smooth animation does not work in a real project

Comment: All the code I showed above, what other files are needed?

Comment: I solved the problem by removing NoopAnimationsModule from package.json thanks !:)

Comment: I too solved the problem after removing NoopAnimationsModule. Thanks !-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing NoopAnimationsModule from package.json thanks !:)

Answer (score 27):

I solved the problem by removing the imported NoopAnimationsModule from the app module..